# Coloring the text depending on numeric value using css

Tags: html, css

I want to color text based on its value, using css.

```
ie. if value is less than 20 --> red ,
    if value is between 20 - 60 --> orange , 
    if value is greater than 60 to 100--> green.
```

I don't want to add any class in the template depending on the value.

I found this Link: [How do I change the background color with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197748/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-with-javascript) but it doesn't suffice as I have too many values to apply color to.
Also I want it to be more maintainable when adding new values in future.

Comment: Without adding a class? the only way you can do this add class dynamically depending on value for text color. Using if...else or switch

Comment: It is ***`IMPOSSIBLE`*** with **ONLY CSS**

Comment: Please give us an example of your code so we can provide you a working solution (ie: post on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Can't you make use of [`rgb` / `rgba` / `hsl`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/color/RGB)? see also [the browser support by mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/color_value)

Comment: Not only do you  want to style based on the content of the element (which isn't possible as of yet), you also want to style conditionally with that content. CSS isn't built for that.

Comment: Yeah.. You've got no chance without putting a script in there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to hide a data cell based on a specific value using just HTML/CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29499952/is-there-a-way-to-hide-a-data-cell-based-on-a-specific-value-using-just-html-css)

Comment: Have you seen my answer? is it good for you?

Answer (score 19):

It is **not possible** only with CSS.

You have to use JavaScript/jQuery to dynamically add the color, based on an `object` color match, and test if the value in the `data-color` HTML attribute is between the range for each element.

The JS code dynamically check if the element attribute is in a color range and apply the matched color.

If you will have to add some color and range in the future, simply **add new values** in the `colorMatch` hash, and update your CSS color class list.

##CSS

```
.red {color:red}
```

###HTML

```
<p data-color="19">Lorem 19</p>
```

###JS

```
var colorMatch = {
    '0-19'     : 'red',
    '20-59'    : 'orange',
    '60-100'   : 'green'
 };
```

[Here is the working fiddle](http://jsbin.com/zotome/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: This approach seems to be very maintainable. thank you.

Comment: What happens if `data-color="19"` is the result of an asp label instead of being "19"?

Comment: In this case, you can't use my JS: you have to previously know the result of the asp label, and code a script according to it.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not consider it cheating to not use the actual `innerHTML` as a condition, but rather construct it from a CSS variable using `content` you could do something like this (just as an effort to not use JS in this case):

```html
<num style="--num:1"></num>
<num style="--num:99"></num>
<num style="--num:165"></num>
```

```css
num {
  --breakpoint: 100;
  --g: calc((clamp(0, var(--num), var(--breakpoint)) - calc(var(--breakpoint) - 1)) * 255);
  color: rgb(0, var(--g), 0);

}

num:after {
   counter-reset: variable var(--num);
   content: counter(variable);
}
```

In this scenario I am coloring any of the numbers green if they are above 100, but more rules can be added using the same method to serve your use-case.

With that said, I think there is probably no scenario where this would ever be useful, other than just technical trivia, as it is more readable to simply change the `class` of the element dynamically using plain JS. Still kinda fun way to use `counter-reset` and `counter` though.

Here is the same example on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/msz1aouc/24/

Answer (score -7):

A simple approach could be
HTML

```
<div class="content">
    <p>high</p>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <p>low</p>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <p>medium</p>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <p>critical</p>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <p>high</p>
</div>

Jquery
var content = $(".content p").text();

    if (content == "high") {

        $(this).css("color", "#ffffff");
    }
   if (content == "low") {

        $(this).css("color", "#ccc");
    }
   if (content == "critical") {

        $(this).css("color", "#000");
    }
```

Comment: Your code does not answer the question. You are matching exact text values, but the problem was about matching int values in some intervals

Comment: I  like it, Just add .valueOf() to convert to numeric and do a numeric case.